# Lua table field changes/missing occasionally

Tags: c++, c++11, lua

I use LUA as a script file, to generate some data, C++ calls specific LUA function , get the return table(one data array), and get every data in it, and render the content afterwards.

The problem happens when c++ get the table. I used a wrapping struct in c++ to hold the LUA table. the structs are returned in a vector. When the struct emplace_back to the vector, everything is just fine. After every data (just as I said, LUA function returns a data array) are emplace_back to the vector, function returns. And outside the function, I checked again, this time, in some data the field "size" is missing.

The difficult part is, this bug happens occasionally. Not predictable, so it is very difficult to trace.

C++ code where "size" field is fine:

```
int TimeLine::NextRandom(std::vector<RandomParam>& container)
{
    //check bake table first
    if(!_bakedTimeline.IsNil())   //_backedTimeline is a LuaTable
    {
        LuaTable ret;
        if(_bakedTimeline.GetTable(_currentPtr, ret))
        {
            int retLength = ret.GetArraySize();
            for(int i = 0; i < retLength; i++)
            {
                LuaTable item;
                if(ret.GetTable(i + 1, item))
                {
                    container.emplace_back(CreateRandomParamFromLuaTable(item)); //CreateRandomParamFromLuaTable is just some method create a RandomParam struct from a LuaTable
                    if(container.back().type == 0)
                    {
                        double size;
                        container.back().luaParam.GetReal("size", size, 999999);
                        if(size > 99999)
                        {
                            //no size, this log never printed out
                            CCLOG("[SIZE_PROBLEM]TimeLine::NextRandom ----> find no size");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return retLength;
        }
    }
....
```

c++ code where size is missing:

```
int Game::_ExecuteCurrentTimeline()
{
    int delta = _timeLine->NextRandom(_objects);
    for(int i = 0; i < delta; i++)
    {
        if(_objects[_objects.size() - 1 - i].type == 0)
        {
            double size;
            _objects[_objects.size() - 1 - i].luaParam.GetReal("size", size, 999999);
            if(size > 99999)
            {
                //no size , occasionally, this log is printed out
                CCLOG("[SIZE_PROBLEM]GAME::_ExecuteCurrentTimeline ----> find no size");
            }
        }
    }
    return delta;
}
```

the struct RandomParam:

```
struct RandomStarParam
{
    int type;
    ...
    LuaTable luaParam;
    RandomStarParam(){}
    RandomStarParam(const RandomStarParam& him) noexcept:type(him.type), luaParam(him.luaParam)
    {
    }
    RandomStarParam(RandomStarParam&& him) noexcept:type(him.type), luaParam(std::move(him.luaParam))
    {
    }
}
```

for reference, the LuaTable's move constructor and GetReal function

```
LuaTable::LuaTable(LuaTable&& lua) noexcept
{
    if(lua._ownner)
    {
        _vm = lua._vm;   //_vm field is a wrapper for lua state
        _ref = lua._ref; //_ref field is the index of table in LUA_REGISTRYINDEX
        if(_vm)
            _vm->AddRef();
        _ownner = true;
        lua._ownner = false;
    }
    else
    {
        _vm = lua._vm;
        _ref = lua._ref;
        if(_vm)
            _vm->AddRef();
        _ownner = false;
    }
}
bool LuaTable::GetReal(const char* field, double& val, double defval)
{
    if(!IsNil())
    {
        Push();
        lua_pushstring(_vm->GetLuaState(), field);
        lua_getintable;
        if (lua_isnumber(_vm->GetLuaState(), -1))
        {
            val = lua_tonumber(_vm->GetLuaState(), -1);
            lua_pop(_vm->GetLuaState(), 2);
            return true;
        }
        lua_pop(_vm->GetLuaState(), 2);
    }
    val = defval;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve], what does `CreateRandomParamFromLuaTable` do?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, After carefully check, I finally find out that it is a mistake in my own logic. Lua is fine.